# Derived AccumulatorParam in py-spark returns EOFException on addInPace function

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a set of json objects of which one key is a nested object of list of keys, which are not common across all the json object. Example object is:

```
{
     id: 'AJDFAKDF',
     class: 'class1',
     nested_object: {
         'key1': 'value1',
         'key2': 'value2',
         'key3': 'value3'
     }
 }
```

The `id` is unique identifier of the object and `key1`, `key2`... will not be same across all objects i.e. 1 object may have `key1` in `nested_object` and the other may not. Also, `class` will vary for each record.

I have 100s of millions of such records and I am interested in finding out the distribution of records by the keys of `nested_object` per `class`. Sample output would be.

```
{
    class1: {
        key1: 32,
        key45: 45,
    },
    class2: {
        key2: 39,
        key45: 100
    }
}
```

I am using pyspark accumulators to generate this distribution. I have derived from the dict class to create a `CounterOfCounters` class. This is on lines of the `Counter` class in `collections` library of python. Much code is copied from the the source code.

```
class CounterOfCounters(dict):
  def __init__(*args, **kwds):
    '''Create a new, empty CounterOfCounters object. Or, initialize 
    the count from another mapping of elements to their Counter.

    >>> c = CounterOfCounters()                 # a new, empty CoC
    >>> c = CounterOfCounters({'a': 4, 'b': 2}) # a new counter from a mapping
    '''
    if not args:
        raise TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object "
                        "needs an argument")
    self, *args = args
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))
    super(CounterOfCounters, self).__init__()
    self.update(*args, **kwds)

  def __missing__(self, key):
    # Needed so that self[missing_item] does not raise KeyError
    return Counter()

  def update(*args, **kwds):
    '''Like dict.update() but add counts instead of replacing them.

    Source can be a dictionary
    '''
    # The regular dict.update() operation makes no sense here because the
    # replace behavior results in the some of original untouched counts
    # being mixed-in with all of the other counts for a mismash that
    # doesn't have a straight-forward interpretation in most counting
    # contexts.  Instead, we implement straight-addition.  Both the inputs
    # and outputs are allowed to contain zero and negative counts.

    # print("In update. [0] ", args)
    if not args:
        raise TypeError("descriptor 'update' of 'CounterOfCounters' object "
                        "needs an argument")
    self, *args = args
    # print("In update. [1] ", self, args)
    if len(args) > 1:
        raise TypeError('expected at most 1 arguments, got %d' % len(args))

    iterable = args[0] if args else None
    if iterable is not None:
        if isinstance(iterable, dict):
            if self:
                self_get = self.get
                for elem, count in iterable.items():
                    if isinstance(count, Counter):
                        self[elem] = count + self_get(elem, Counter())
                    else:
                        raise TypeError("values can only be of type Counter")
            else:
                for elem, count in iterable.items():
                    if isinstance(count, Counter):
                        self[elem] = count
                    else:
                        raise TypeError("values can only be of type Counter")
        else:
            raise TypeError("values can only be of type Counter")
    if kwds:
        raise TypeError("Can not process **kwds as of now")
```

I then derive from `AccumulatorParam` my custom AccumulatorParam class.

```
class KeyAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, value):
        c = CounterOfCounters(
            dict.fromkeys(
                value.keys(), 
                Counter()
            )
        )
        return c

    def addInPlace(self, ac1, ac2):
        ac1.update(ac2)
        return ac1
```

Then I define the accumulator variable and the function to add it.

```
keyAccum = sc.accumulator(
    CounterOfCounters(
        dict.fromkeys(
            ['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4'],
            Counter()
        )
    ), 
    KeyAccumulatorParam()
)

def accumulate_keycounts(rec):
    global keyAccum
    c = Counter(list(rec['nested_object'].keys()))
    keyAccum.add(CounterOfCounters({
        rec['class']: c
    }))
```

After which I call `accumulate_keycounts` foreach record in rdd.

```
test_rdd.foreach(accumulate_keycounts)
```

On doing this, I get the end of file exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1$$anonfun$read$1.apply$mcVI$sp(PythonRDD.scala:200)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:199)
    ... 25 more
```

Some more additional info. I am using spark 2.2.1 on my MacBook Pro Retina (2013 8GB) for testing my function. The `test_rdd` has only ~20 records. It is a sample from larger rdd of ~200000 records.

I am not sure why this error is happening. I have enough memory to finish the task. The accumulator is commutative and associative as per the requirements of accumulator.

What I have debugged till now and figured out is that the error happens after first record is processed i.e. first time `addInPlace` is called. The `CounterOfCounters.update` function returns normally. But after that the `EOFException` occurs.

Any tips to debug or pointers to the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: While convoluted, and very un-Sparkish, this code won't cause the problem alone. Looks like there is some other problem underneath.

Comment: any suggestions on what is a spark-way of doing it?

Comment: also, the rest of the code is simply getting a spark context, reading textFile using `sc.textFile` into an rdd, transforming text to json using `json.loads` and `rdd.map`, sampling 0.01% of the RDD using `rdd.sample`, and running `foreach` on the sampled rdd.

Comment: Have you found an answer yet ?

Comment: Don't remember now, but I had solved it then. However, as @Alpert.Turker said, this is very un-Sparkish way of doing things. So reedited this.